# Pause slide show on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow, mousehover

I have the following script to run a slideshow, that works just fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 5000);


var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 500, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 500, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('a.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
     moveRight();
});
});
```

But I want it to pause on mouse hover, and I've tried a few other suggestions I found here on SO (including the one below), but couldn't make any of them work with the code I have.
Any ideas? Thanks.

```
$("#slider ul").mouseover(function() {
$("#slider ul").trigger('pause', true);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.stop()`, `clearInterval()`

```
// define reference to `setInterval()` call
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 5000);

// stop animations, clear `interval`
$("#slider ul").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).stop();
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clearInterval()` to remove the interval.

Comment: clearInterval() is a function which works exactly opposite to setInterval().

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
var timerObject=null; 

function StartSlide(){
timerObject = setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 5000);
}

function stopSlide(){
clearInterval(timerObject)
}

$("#slider ul").mouseover(function() {
stopSlide()
});

$("#slider ul").mouseleave(function() {
StartSlide()
});
```

Comment: This did make the slide stop on mouseover, but it removed the auto start. So it would *only* start after mouseleave. =/

Answer (score 0):

```
.stop() | jQuery API
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyUYN/1229/) Example:

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $("#slider").flexisel({
      visibleItems: 3,
      animationSpeed: 1000,
      itemsToScroll: 6,
      autoPlay: true,
      autoPlaySpeed: 3000,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
      responsiveBreakpoints: {
        portrait: {
          changePoint: 480,
          visibleItems: 1
        },
        landscape: {
          changePoint: 640,
          visibleItems: 3
        },
        tablet: {
          changePoint: 768,
          visibleItems: 4
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i hope this work for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.